# A relation I have never seen before

Tags: probability-theory, statistical-mechanics

I was going through the book **Information, Physics and Computation** by Mezard and Montanari, where in Chapter 8, I found the following relation:

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E} \log Z = \lim_{n\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{n} \log (\mathbb{E} Z^n)~,
\end{equation}

where $Z$ is the partition function of the random energy model (REM) (to be precise, $Z = \sum_{j=1}^{2^N} \exp(-\beta E_j)$, where $E_1,\cdots,E_{2^N}$ are i.i.d. $N(0,N/2)$).

My question is that, does the above relation hold for any non-negative random variable $Z$, or is it a specific property of the REM partition function? I am confused, because I have not seen this relation anywhere before.

Many thanks.

Comment: Limit of power mean...

Comment: Couldn't quite get it...

Comment: This holds for any non-negative random variable $Z$.  $E(\log Z)$ is the log of the geometric mean of $Z$ and $1/n \log (E Z^n)$ is the log of the $n$th power mean.  A proof that the limit of the $n$th power mean, as $n \to 0$, is the geometric mean, can be found at Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean) for the discrete case.  This is a comment instead of an answer because your problem isn't restricted to the discrete case.